# Embed a dynamic HTML page in reactjs application

Tags: reactjs

I am migrating a JSF app to Node/React js. One of the requirements is to show an html page that is dynamically
  requested from a third party in one of the  on the page. The third party html is complex - it has its 
  own javascript and css links to render a canvas. Let me know if this is feasible.

I have 
    checked in debugger that the requested html arrives successfully.
    made sure that it is a valid html by copying it to a file and opening it in different browsers
    made sure that all the referred scripts and css are accessible
    made sure there are no CORS error
    tried wrapping the html in  tag
Please see below compressed code. It compiles, rest of the page is rendered but div with third party html
  remains blank. If I inspect the div I can see the html but I think none of the javascript code is executed.

```
class STMDrwaingtDiv extends React.Component
  {
     constructor(props)
     {
        //Just create some state variables to track the http request status and 
        //store the response text
     }

     getPrevDrawing(caller)
     {
        //make http request
        //caller.setState({cnvHtml:"<object> "+prevDrawing+" </object>"});
        //I have tries wrapping the html in <object> tag - does not work
        caller.setState({cnvHtml:prevDrawing});
     }
     componentDidMount()
     {
        this.getPrevDrawing(this);
     }
     render()
     {
       //display progessbar handle errors etc.
       else
       {
         return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html:this.state.chartHtml}} />;
       }
     }
     }
```

Comment: Try using an `<iframe>` instead of a `<div>` and look into the `srcDoc` attribute. Alternatively you might just be able to set the `src` of the iframe to the 3rd party url

Comment: Thanks @kht. Using frames with src="url" worked. srcdoc attribute does not seem to be supported on MS browsers. If you make this an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Just in case anyone lands here searching for same issue - The problem was that aynchrously loaded javascripts do no execute. I wasted a couple of days trying to jam them in with innerHtml, dynamically creating script node and adding them to DOM etc. Also this is not really a react issue. I guess this is how html works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

Use an `<iframe>` instead of a `<div>`.  Iframes are meant to be used to embed HTML documents (web pages) inside of other HTML documents! Setting the `src` attr of the iframe to the 3rd party URL should embed their HTML automatically in your page.